# Issue using variable and TOP clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I get the following error when trying to run the code below:

> The number of rows in the TOP clause must be an integer.

The @constCnt variable is declared as a SMALLINT and @thresh is declared as a DECIMAL(6,4).  When I execute `select (floor((@constCnt*(1+@thresh))))` I get an integer value returned with no decimals.

Any ideas how to get around this?

```
    select top (@constCnt) * 
    into #temp
    from (
            select top (floor((@constCnt*(1+@thresh)))) pt.*,
                inLast = CASE WHEN lh.code IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            from #pretemp pt
            left join #last lh
            on lh.code = pt.code
            order by em desc ) a    
    order by inlast desc, emr desc, code
```

Comment: have you tried CAST(floor((@constCnt*(1+@thresh))) as INT)?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work.

EDIT:  Ack, error in the way I set it up--looks like it's working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast the variable:

```
select top (cast(@constCnt as int)) *
...
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I get the following error:  

[Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.]

EDIT:  Messed up the syntax...seems to be working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining another variable:

```
declare @constCnt2 int = floor((@constCnt*(1+@thresh)))
```

And then use this in the subquery.

```
select top (@constCnt) *
into #temp
from (select top (@constCnt2) pt.*,
             inLast = CASE WHEN lh.code IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
      from #pretemp pt left join
           #last lh
           on lh.code = pt.code
      order by em desc
     ) a
order by inlast desc, emr desc, code
```